# Celery Flower consuming more than 100% cpu load

Tags: celery, flower

We are using celery flower for monitoring the celery workers. We are using rabbitmq as message broker. The problem here is after 2 days of starting celery flower monitoring service, it starts consuming more than 100% of cpu load. Then we will get messages of cpu oveload. We are not able to figure out why celery flower consumes lot of cpu load. Please share your suggestions.

Comment: issue was fixed in latest version. upgrade to latest version and try again. https://github.com/mher/flower/issues/201

Comment: okay thanks Anand, will try it out

Comment: I'm having a similar problem on Flower 0.7.3. Which version should contain the fix linked above?

Comment: @ChillarAnand : Same problem.I upgraded flower 0.7.2 to 0.7.3, but the problem is still there. Can you please provide a link here .

Comment: @ChillarAnand Problem persists for me in Flower 0.7.3

Comment: Use master version, install the master version and try, pip install https://github.com/mher/flower/zipball/master